# How to set up autologin with Fritzbox?

Tags: fritzbox

Login Page from Fritz.box

```
<div id="dialogContent" name="" class="dialog_content">
    <form id="loginForm" name="" class="loginForm" method="post" action="">
        <div id="" name="" class="formular">
            <p id="" name="" class="">Melden Sie sich mit Ihrem Benutzernamen und Ihrem Kennwort an.</p>
            <label for="uiViewUser">Benutzername</label>
            <select id="uiViewUser" name="uiUser" class="">
                <option value="">Bitte wählen ...</option>
                <option value="ftpuser">ftpuser</option>
                <option value="mha">mha</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <p id="uiSelectUsername" name="" class="form_input_note ErrorMsg hidden">Bitte geben Sie einen Benutzernamen an.</p>
            <label for="uiPass">Kennwort</label>
            <input type="password" id="uiPass" name="uiPass">
            <div id="uiLoginError" name="" class="hidden">
                <p id="" name="" class="error_text">Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen.</p>
                <p id="" name="" class="error_text">Haben Sie sich vielleicht vertippt oder fehlt Ihnen die Zugangsberechtigung für diesen Bereich?</p>
                <p id="uiWait" name="" class="error_text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="" name="" class="btn_form_foot">
            <input type="hidden" id="uiResp" name="response" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="" name="lp" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="">
            <div id="forgot_pass" name="" class="">
                <a id="" name="" class="" target="" href="">Kennwort vergessen?</a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="submitLoginBtn" name="" class="" tabindex="3">Anmelden</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I set the username value and password value to autologin from html file ?

My code for autologin:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<!--
function login() {
document.form1.action="http://fritz.box";
document.form1.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="login()">

<form NAME="form1" id=form1 method="POST" >

<input type=hidden name="uiUser" value="admin">
<input type=hidden name="uiPass" value="mypassword">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong to autofill the Login data? The code not work to autologin.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your usecase? What do you mean by "autologin"? Do you simply want to bypass the login screen by submitting your password automatically?